# 3D object tracking with two webcams

Tags: python, opencv, 3d

I am using a ping pong ball on my Elbow. I can track it with OpenCV in python and extract x and y in every frame but the problem is; I need z too. So I added the second cam in coronal plane.

If you are not familiar here is the picture:

[image]

My first cam was on sagittal plane. I don't know how can I sync them. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can get x and y coordinates from one cam, it's the same getting y and z from the other cam. Get rid of the extra y and you've got x, y, and z.

Comment: the problem is the y in y ,z is not sync with y in x , y.I dont know ho to calibrate

Comment: if they're on the same machine you should use two threads to extract the frames concurrently

Comment: or use `grab` on both cams first and then use `retrieve` however there would still be a slight delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several solutions:

- positioning your webcams in 2 perpendicular planes (what you did) and manually measure the distance between them in terms of (x,y,0).

Then you have your first webcam at (0,0,0) and the second one at (15,16,0) for example. From there you can easily deduce the transformation between the images, see [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations)

It is a rotation of 90° + a translation, so if you rotation is along the z axis, the transformation matrix would be:

```
0    1   15

-1   0   16

0    0   1
```

or

```
0    -1   15

1    0    16

0    0    1
```

depending if the rotation is of + or - 90°. If you've got a doubt, check on your data.

- Another solution: position your two webcams then put reference points (4 of them should be good, defining a cartesian coordinate system) in the filming area, and decide that they will define your frame of reference. Then you transform the input from the two webcams to get their coordinates into that frame. I guess you could do that by using some of the math in the link I gave you and by checking your result in OpenCV.